# SDL poll event inverting w with z and viceversa

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm doing a simple camera movement with the WASD keys:

```
switch (k) {
    case SDLK_w:
        this->up = true;
        break;
    case SDLK_s:
        this->down = true;
        break;
    case SDLK_a:
        this->left = true;
        break;
    case SDLK_d:
        this->right = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

It's pretty self explanatory. But when I press `w` it simply doesn't detect that button pressing. If I press `a` or `d` or `s` it works. The cool thing about it is that if I just change `SDLK_w` to any other button (let's say `SDLK_q`) keeping the same exact code, it just works. It's not an issue of how I handle `this->up` because even if I print something on the screen inside the `case SDLK_w:` and I press w it doesn't print anything.

PS: obviously my w key is not broken otherwise I would have had trouble writing this post doWn.

What's wrong with w?

Comment: What value does SDLK_w represent?

Comment: @Loggie, it represent 119 and it's the exact key code value for the Mac keyboard. I've just checked with a specific application.

Comment: What happens if you cout the value of k in the default case and press the w key?

Comment: @Loggie, It prints `122`, it's quite strange.

Comment: @Loggie, `122` is the Z key. And if I press the Z key on the default values it cout `119`...

Comment: That is very strange indeed.. What version of SDL are you using?

Comment: @Loggie, the latest of the `1.2` release for Mac OS X. Using a show-key-codes [application](http://softwares.bajram.com/softwares/) it correctly shows that W = 119 and Z = 122. I'm using Snow Leopard (10.6.8)

Comment: I am completely baffled by this. If the value of SDLK_w is definitely 119 then I see no possible reason for your SDLK_w case to be executed when you press z and not w. Only thing I can suggest is you post on the SDL forums and see if anyone there is able to help.

Comment: I don't know if this would affect it but out of curiosity, what is your keyboard region set to?

Comment: @Loggie, I probably have the Italian keyboard. I had the same idea just 1 minute ago and checked and the only buttons that matters to this problem that changes are that Y = Z. On the left side from bottom to down I have Q-A-Z instead of Q-A-Y (of USA?).

Comment: Ahh. Does switching the region to UK/US fix the problem? I personally can't see it but I've never had any problems using UK keyboards. Q-A-Z is US as well as far as I know, but definitely for UK.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I tried printing out something inside the case and it didn't printed.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I saw that. What version of SDL is this? Are you using 2.0 or 1.3?

Comment: @NicolBolas, the latest of 1.2 for Mac OS X.

Comment: @Loggie, changing from Italian PRO to USA doesn-t change anything.

Comment: Just for reference [here's the post on the SDL forum](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=8630&highlight=stack+overflow).

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on the type of  keyboard you are using, actually your W and Z key could be inversed depending on your keyboard layout. I recommand you try ALT+SHIFT.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SDLK_w for this as it gives you whatever key actually gives you a W letter, whereas what you want is the key that you'd expect at the W position regardless of the layout, you do this by using scancodes, in this case SDL_SCANCODE_W.